# python executable not working correctly

Tags: python, tweepy

I've written a python script that stores tweets in real time using the `tweepy` module. The script runs fine.

Then I tried to make the script executable by adding `#!/usr/bin/python`and then running the `chmod +x stream_tweets.py` command on the terminal. Now, if I run the script using `python stream_tweets.py`, the script runs fine but running it with `./stream_tweets.py` shows me an error that there is no module named tweepy!

[image]

I think it might have something to do with the environment variables, but I don't have much idea about those. Can anyone fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `#!/usr/bin/python` use either what `which python` says, or `#!/usr/bin/env python`

Comment: it works!
but I have another question. I only have python 2.7 installed, why do i need to use env python? my other scripts which also run on various modules run fine

Comment: env python takes into consideration of your current *nix user's environment Python executable, a lazy yet elegant approach of doing really anything involving hash-bangs. Your other scripts may be using modules that are available associated to their specified Python environment

Answer (score 0):

Install tweepy, as mentioned [here](https://github.com/tweepy/tweepy)

Comment: umm, thats how I installed tweepy in the first place. Its working normally, the problem is just with the executable.